# How do I add things to a database based on their rank and a button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

I have a website that is made for my family who is into NASCAR. There is this page I work on the most called the **Roster** page. The drivers are put into 5 ranks (A, B, C, D, and E) based on a JSON file from NASCAR. There is a button on the right side of all drivers called "Add". Currently, it does nothing. I want to make it change the driver for the user. For example, if the user picks Kyle Busch who may be in Rank A, it will change their driver1 to Kyle Busch. Rank B, driver 2. And so on.

I currently add drivers by them having to fill out a text box, but that may get annoying. Here is what I have so far for the button and stuff:

```
$("#dummy_" + pos).before("<p>" + person.driver_name + " <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Add'>");
```

^ Javascript

Below is how I do it now:

```
    if(isset($_POST['add_driver1'])){
  $driver1 = htmlentities($_POST['driver1']);

  $conn->query("UPDATE users SET driver1='$driver1' WHERE id='$user->id'");
  header('Location: ../roster/');
}
```

^PHP

```
              <form action="" method="Post">
             <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="driver1" placeholder="Driver 1" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="Set" name="add_driver1">
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

^HTML

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `htmlentities()` does not protect against SQL injections..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list to map the rank to a field:

```
$rankToField = [
    'A' => 'driver1',
    'B' => 'driver2',
    'C' => 'driver3',
    'D' => 'driver4',
    'E' => 'driver5',
];
```

You can do this by creating a form for each "add":

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="rank" value="<RANK_FROM_JSON>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="driver" value="<DRIVER_FROM_JSON>" />
    <input type="submit" .../>
</form>
```

In your PHP-Script you save it like:

```
$field = $rankToField[$_POST['rank']];
$driver = $_POST['diver'];
/* insert... */
```

In case the JSON offers a driver ID you should just sumit the ID through the form and search for the values in your JSON file before inserting.

You may want to have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php to replace your `htmlentities`

And Prepared Statements to be safe: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php